# How to Keep Missing Values in Ordinal Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic, python, scikit-learn, missing-data, ordinal-data

I’m using `mord` package in python to do ordinal logit regression (predict response to movie rating 1-5 stars).

One of my predictor variables is also ordinal but there are some missing values where the viewer skipped a question because it wasn’t applicable due to skip logic from a prior question or because they missed it. What’s the best way to indicate a value is “missing” and/or “not applicable” while also retaining the ordinal nature of this predictor variable for everyone else? I don’t think I should delete this viewer or try to impute the value.

I get an error if I leave the `NaN`. I thought about dummy coding so I have something like question5_never, question5_sometimes, question5_always, question5_na, question5_missing, but I not sure.

Comment: If using it as a predictor, why do you need the variable to remain ordinal? Ordinal ogistic regression doesn't treat ordinal predictors any differently from nominal predictors.

Comment: @Noah in this case, will my approach of dummy coding in the way I described work? What’s the right way to handle this?

Comment: It really depends on the context. For questions with skip logic (planned missingness), does it even make sense for those that skipped this question to have it as a predictor? Maybe you need to stratify your analysis based on whether the question was a forced skip or not (e.g., males skipping a question about pregnancy implies you should stratify by sex). For people that just didn't answer the question but were shown it, you need to use standard missing data techniques that rely on assumptions that you need to verify in your own data (e.g., MCAR, MAR, MNAR).